# BSOD when plug in HDMI cable - AMD Radeon HD 6630M

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, amd-radeon

I tried to use the HDMI cable to connect my laptop with a TV. But the laptop immediately got BSOD when the HDMI cable is pluged into the laptop (the other side has been pluged into TV).

The BSOD is caused by "atikmdag.sys" and it happens every time.

Anyone who knows the root cause and solution?

OS:Win7 Home edition
Graphic card model: AMD Radeon HD 6630M

**EDIT1:**

I replaced my driver from OEM with the latest package from AMD website.

I don't see the BSOD now. But I've got a new problem with HDMI output.

Neither the resolution nor the color of the output looks good on my TV. There are black frame around the TV screen.

Still the driver issue?

Answer (score 1):

`atikmdag.sys` is the AMD Catalyst graphic card driver. So update your graphic card driver, please:

32Bit: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-32.aspx

64Bit: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx

Comment: Thanks. The BSOD has gone though the HDMI output looks weird now.

Comment: this is still a driver issue. Try the drivers from AMD which are newer compared to the drivers that the OEMs provide on their pages.